# align image to right of paragraph css

Tags: html, css

I'd like to align an image to the right of a paragraph, and I'd like to be able to do so without having to set a fixed width on the paragraph along with some padding away from the image. how can I do that?

https://jsfiddle.net/mnakoajk/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<img src="https://media.tenor.co/images/fe795771396053d4e1d55904dcf20298/tenor.gif" />
```

Comment: This will help you to understand it - https://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101

Comment: First, the image need a padding or margin in some way or else the text will align all the way to its side, second, what should happen with text that flows beyond the image's height?

Answer (score 4):

Place `<img>` inside `<p>`.

```
<p>
<img src="https://media.tenor.co/images/fe795771396053d4e1d55904dcf20298/tenor.gif" />
is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uvew5yw2/

Answer (score 1):

Replace `display: inline-block;` in both of the elements with `display: block;` or remove it completely. if it doesn't work you can add `width:x px` to the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Move the IMG above the P tag and then remove float and display from the P tag.

```
p {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: auto;
}
```

Here is updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mnakoajk/5/

and then put margin left and margin bottom on the IMG tag to keep paragraph text at a safe distance.

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mnakoajk/6

Comment: put margin left and margin bottom on the IMG tag to keep paragraph text at a safe distance. https://jsfiddle.net/mnakoajk/6/

Answer (score 1):

Specify the paragraph width. Like `width: 55%;`

Comment: I want a solution where you don't need to set a width

Answer (score 1):

Change order of p and img. And remove inline-block property from p element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

img {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://media.tenor.co/images/fe795771396053d4e1d55904dcf20298/tenor.gif" />
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```

Comment: If you want border to be visible around image, just add them to div wrapper and set border there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/mnakoajk/1/

I will explain: you can use a wrapper div for both `<p>` and `<img>` tags. The div wrapper must have this rule:

```
display: flex;
```

So you can put inner elements next to each others. After this, you can control width and height of the img tag.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Adding/deleting or replacing display property won't help since

and  both are block level elements. Only by adding width this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in this JSFiddle. I have added css in the style tag in html but i can change it in few moments.

https://jsfiddle.net/o6f2z27n/5/

Now the idea is to set width to be 60% and 30% of paragraph and img respectively

```
     <div class="container">
         <p></p>  
         <img />
    </div>
```

Comment: I want a solution where you don't need to set a width

Comment: Hi, check this fiddle. I have updated the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/o6f2z27n/16/

Answer (score 0):

You can put both in a container and use flexbox. For the sample below i used "body" as the container. See code below

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
p {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

<img src="https://media.tenor.co/images/fe795771396053d4e1d55904dcf20298/tenor.gif" />
```